# JavaScript revealing module pattern public variable not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, revealing-module-pattern

I'm using Angular service with a Revealing Module pattern.  The service internally pulls string resources from a web service and makes them available via the 'Strings' public variable.  I have to initialize the private 'strings' variable because it is referenced before the service call is made.

I get the proper string data back from the service and copy it to the private 'strings' variable.  However, when the client references the public 'Strings', it is still retaining its original value.

Any idea what I am doing wrong, or how to get public 'Strings' to update?

```
'use strict';

io1App.factory('Resources', ['$rootScope', 'DataService', '$q',
function ($rootScope, DataService, $q) {

   var urlBase = '/api/sfc/resource';

    // Need to pre-define 'ERROR_HEADER', since it is referenced in Index.html...before we have a chance to download it from the server.
   var strings = {
       'ERROR_HEADER': 'Error!'
   };

    var getStringResources = function (locale) {

        var url = urlBase + '/' + locale;

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var promise = DataService.GetMethod(url);

        // Note that DataService.GetMethod(...) is returning a $q promise
        promise.then(function (data) {
            strings = data;
            deferred.resolve();
        },
        function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        Strings: strings,
        GetStringResources: getStringResources
    }
}]);
```

The service call sets the returned data to the private 'strings' variable

```
promise.then(function (data) {
            strings = data;
            deferred.resolve();
        },
```

Private 'strings' is now showing the following (via Chrome Developer tools):

```
strings = {
       'ERROR_HEADER': 'Error!'
       'INVALID_PROCESS_ORDER': 'Process Order [%d] could not be entered because it does not belong to Manfacturing Order [%d]',
       'DUPLICATE_PROCESS_ORDER': 'Process Order [%d] already entered.',
       'USER_NOT_ITAR': 'Manufacturing order [%d] is ITAR, and you are not ITAR approved.  You cannot proceed with this order.  Please contact your supervisor.'
   };
```

Yet when is reference public 'Strings' in the Angular controllers, 'Strings' is still referencing the original value of private 'strings'.

Resource.Strings:

```
{
   'ERROR_HEADER': 'Error!'
};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing the `strings` variable completely with `data`. They are different objects and have different references, so any client code that has a reference to the previous `strings` object will not see the change.

Instead of replacing, you could augment the existing `strings` object.

```
promise.then(function (data) {
    // Merge properties into `strings`
    // You could also use any other "extension" technique, e.g. _.extend()
    for (var k in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            strings[k] = data[k];
        }
    }
    deferred.resolve();
},
```

Comment: Thanks voithos...that did resolve the issue.  I have been using a repository in a similar manner, and had not run into this apparent reference vs. value issue...I need to read more about this.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript object you return from your factory method is never updated with the new strings object. You need to retain a reference to it to be able to update the "public view":

```
service = {
    Strings: strings,
    GetStringResources: getStringResources
};
return service;
```

Then update your `.then` callback to update both the private variable as well as the public service object:

```
.then(function(data) {
    strings = service.strings = data;
    deferred.resolve(data); // don't need to resolve this with the strings, but why not?
}, function error(){...});
```

However, since you no longer really have "private data" (only a private reference to the variable which is public), you don't really need to have the private strings variable at all:

```
io1App.factory('Resources', ['$rootScope', 'DataService', '$q',
function ($rootScope, DataService, $q) {

    var urlBase = '/api/sfc/resource';

    var service = {
        // Need to pre-define 'ERROR_HEADER', since it is referenced in Index.html...before we have a chance to download it from the server.
        Strings: { 'ERROR_HEADER': 'Error!' },
        GetStringResources: function (locale) {
            var url = urlBase + '/' + locale;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = DataService.GetMethod(url);

            // Note that DataService.GetMethod(...) is returning a $q promise
            promise.then(function (data) {
                service.strings = data;
                deferred.resolve(data); // don't need to resolve this with the strings, but why not?
            },
        function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks squid314..interesting...I will try this method too.

Comment: No problem. As @voithos said, it is a reference vs value issue. Basically you had 2 pointers (or references) to the same value and you were only updating 1 of them to the new value (specifically the private one).